# Applescript Check Whether Password is Correct

Tags: authentication, applescript, prompt

I am making an app that requires root privileges. I am new to applscript and apologize if this is a dumb question but what I am trying to do is check whether a password is correct. I get the password string from a prompt like this:

```
set thePass to the text returned of (display dialog "I need you to enter your password" default answer "" buttons {"Okay"} default button 1 with icon file ((path to resource "Icon.icns") as text) with hidden answer)
```

I need to check whether `thePass` is actually their password before proceeding. I do not want to just use the default password prompt. Is there a way to do this?

I already tried a try, on error statement to test the password, it just prompts for the password with the default prompt if the one entered is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay here is how I just solved it:
1) Get the password in a variable

2) Try to use sudo to run a command (using stdin as input), this will fail if the password is incorrect

```
try
    do shell script "echo '" & thePass & "' | sudo -S :"
onerror
    display alert "Incorrect Password!"
end try
```

Answer (score 1):

No idea what you're trying to do, but if you want to execute a shell script using sudo you should do

```
do shell script shellScriptVariable with administrator privileges
```

without the "sudo" in the shell script. You'll automatically get an error dialog if the password is wrong.